# A title attribute on a nested tag inside a button tag does not show on FX

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am using a `button` tag which is has some tags inside it and I want to add a `title` attribute to that tag, but it's not working. I don't want to give a `title` on the `button` tag for several reasons.

The problem is only in the Mozilla browser - it's working fine in all other browsers.

```
<button style="width:150px">
<span class="icon nearby_airport lt"></span>
Nearby Airport
<p>
    <span id="NearBycontract">
        <span class="fpcurrencytext">$</span>
        <span class="fpamount fpMatrixRoundCeil" title="587.81" >587</span>
        <sup>
            <span class="fpamount fpMatrixSuper" title="587.81">.81</span>
        </sup>
    </span>
</p>
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wBufb/9/).

Comment: it is the same in mozilla and chrome

Comment: Works fine on my Chrome.

Comment: That markup looks so wrong on so many levels -at least do `<span class="fpamount fpMatrixSuper" title="587.81"><sup>.81</sup></span>` http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/MuSpu/

Comment: its ok in both chrome and firefox (latest releases) maybe adding your css here, will help to understand the problem?

Comment: works for me in mozilla. what title tag do you mean? if <title> then im pretty sure that is only allowed within <head>

Comment: Firefox has a history of not showing titles. I do indeed not see the title on FX18/XP not FX17/Win7 unless I add it to the button tag - @user1721135, all tags can have a title which is shown onmouseover like the image ALT attribute

Comment: yes, attribute title ofc. i was confused because the OP read title tag

Comment: @mplungjan i have to do this due to some reasons.This what the requirment is...any solution for this...

Comment: i have to show one tooltip on button tag and title on span tag this is what the requirement is

Comment: Please elaborate on "Some reason" and can you copy the title attribute to the button tag after load using script?

Comment: i have to give one tooltip on button and want to give title only on numeric digit not on whole button @mplungjan

Comment: Surely if you are going to give a tooltip to the button this will override any titles given to the numbers too

Comment: @Pete but it shouldn't show on ie as well then its working fine in ie.